# better solution?

Tags: php, arrays, random, generate-scripts

This script picks element inside of the array and print it.

```
<?php
    $word = array("THE", "QUICK", "BROWN", "FOX", "JUMPS");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($word, 2);
    echo $word[$rand_keys[0]];
    echo $word[$rand_keys[1]];
?>
```

it works but i'm using some function

> array_diff();

which on my script search from the `$word` variable and removes from the element list
example:

> $word = array("THE", "QUICK", "BROWN", "FOX", "JUMPS");
>
> $sentence = array("QUICK", "BROWN");
>
> $input = array_diff($word, $sentence);

so `$input` is containing `array("THE", "FOX", "JUMPS");` right?

and I apply to the script like to this:

```
<?php
    $word = array("THE", "QUICK", "BROWN", "FOX", "JUMPS");
    $sentence = array("QUICK", "BROWN");
    $input = array_diff($word, $sentence);
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
    echo $input[$rand_keys[0]];
    echo $input[$rand_keys[1]];
?>
```

it also works because it contains 3 elements on the array. If I do more **filtering** and the

> $input

variable contains only 1 element ex: `$input` only contains `array("BROWN");` the script won't run anymore and getting errors like:

> Warning: array_rand(): Second argument has to be between 1 and the
>   number of elements in the array in
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in

how can I run the script if the array element containing only **1**?

I've come this far it works but is there any better solution?

```
<?php
$word = array("THE", "QUICK", "BROWN", "FOX", "JUMPS");

if(count($input) >= 2)
{
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
    echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
    echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
}
else
{
    echo end($input);
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the goal of this script; i.e. what do you want the final output to be? It doesn't really make any sense to try to select random keys from an array of length 1.

Comment: final output is i want script keeps running when I do filtering like it only contains 1 element I shows the last element not errors

Answer (score 1):

Error message is simple and easy to understand. You can't use number bigger than count of elements in second argument of `array_rand()`.

Before calling this function check what is count of elements and in case it's only one, use this element without calling `array_rand()`. Also be prepared for situation when you've got no elements at all.

Comment: i answered my question and did what you told me is there any other better solution? like using for loop?

Comment: @Destiny Don't use loop for something you can check with one if.

Comment: @ElonThan I have similar error in my code but only if there is a 'test' keyword in array.